# Mongoose model with array logic

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently training with Mongoose and to do so I'm building a little messaging app.

I have a collection of user, here is the **User.js** :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

now I want to write a chatroom model that should contain a list of users, how should I proceed ? Here is my current **Chatroom.js** :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ChatroomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String,
  members: ???
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Chatroom', ChatroomSchema);
```

Finally I would like to know how to post a user in that members array when creating a chatroom, here is my route code for **/chatroom** :

```
router.route('/chatroom')
.post(function(req, res) {
  var chatroom = new Chatroom();
  chatroom.name = req.body.name;
  chatroom.password = encrypt(req.body.password,chatroom.name);
  chatroom.members = ???;

  chatroom.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);

    res.json({ message: 'Chatroom created!' });
  });
});
```

Is there a specific way to bind a user to the members array or should I just define members as an array of string :

```
members : {username:String}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Population would be ideal in your case. From the **[docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)**:

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified
>   paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

Population will seamlessly help you bring data from the `Users` collection into your `Chatroom` model. Consider the following example to illustrate this approach:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ChatroomSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Chatroom', ChatroomSchema);
```

In your chatroom schema definition, you add a list of primary surrogate keys to each object, called ObjectId, referenced as `_id` in the data by surrounding the field definition `members` in square brackets to get this functionality. These will be the keys used to refer to documents in the `User` collections.

**Note**:- When you define the references, the `ref` attribute must match exactly the model name in your model definition else you will get an error (suppose you refer to a non-existing `Member` model or `Users`)

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Member"..
```

**Reading the data**

This is where Mongoose population shows how easy and fast it is to makes reads of documents very straightforward through its **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)** function. So for instance, to show the referenced `users` in a chatroom, call the **[`populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)** method with the name of that field in a string as a parameter e.g.

```
Chatroom.findOne({"_id": chatId})
    .populate("members")
    .exec(err, chats) { ... }
```

**Writing data**

When you save data for the `Chatroom` model, you will also need to save the references to the users. For instance, when a new `Chatroom` is created, you'll need an array of `User` references saved as the members field:

```
router.route('/chatroom')
.post(function(req, res) {
    var chatroom = new Chatroom();
    var usersIds = ["54b5659536cd5250a3a93bd3", "54b5659836cd5250a3a93bd4"]; // <-- an array with members ids, for example.
    chatroom.name = req.body.name;
    chatroom.password = encrypt(req.body.password,chatroom.name);
    chatroom.members = usersIds; 

    chatroom.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Chatroom created!' });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's pretty helpful ! I'm using token authentication and I'm currently stocking the username inside the token. I'm thinking about stocking the User ObjectID instead to avoid having to do another request to get the ID with the username when defining a first user in members array. Do you know if there is any good practice concerning this ?

Comment: You can pretty much use any data type in your members field as long as it's a unique identifier to the referenced model, so in this instance it's not only restricted to the `ObjectId` but you can use the username as reference e.g. `members: [{ type: String, ref: 'User' }]` and then just save the array of usernames when saving a chatroom instance. So this saves you the headache of storing the user's `ObjectId` in the token as well when you can just use the username (which would be unique as well). That's another alternative but generally depends on your application needs.

Comment: Will populate still work in this case ? If I use the username instead of the ObjectID ? 

I now have this error (JSON result of my request) :

`{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"test\" at path \"_id\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "kind": "ObjectId",
  "value": "test",
  "path": "_id"
}`

Here is my request :

`.get(function(req, res) { Chatroom.find({ 'members': req.decoded.username }).populate("members").exec(function(err, chatrooms) { ... });});`

Comment: Forgot to mention that if you want to use the `username` as your user reference then you'd have to define the `_id` as `String` in your `User` schema definition since by default Mongoose treats `_id` field as an `ObjectId`.

Comment: Ok so actually I can't use the username I need to use the _id anyway right ? So I have to stock the username in this _id field instead of the custom username field I created ?

Comment: When you use something other than `ObjectId` as the `_id` field, you're taking on the responsibility of managing these values yourself. `ObjectIds` are autogenerated and require no extra management.

Answer (score 0):

Try with referenced documents

**Chatroom.js**

```
var ChatroomSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String,
  members: [Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref = 'user']
});
```

**Controller**

```
router.route('/chatroom')
.post(function(req, res) {
  var chatroom = new Chatroom();
  chatroom.name = req.body.name;
  chatroom.password = encrypt(req.body.password,chatroom.name);
  chatroom.members = req.user; // if the user is authenticated

  chatroom.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);

    res.json({ message: 'Chatroom created!' });
  });
});
```